# How do I map URL paths to directories on my server?

Tags: apache-2.2

At the moment I have a directory containing various web-facing products, such as a Drupal site, a wiki, etc, something like this.

`/srv/www`

`/srv/www/blog`

`/srv/www/wiki`

`/srv/www/sometestphpapp`

At the moment, I've got one apache2 virtualhost config in `/sites-available` that simply sets ServerName to the domain `mydomain.com` sets the docroot to `/srv/www` and sets basic auth. If I want to bring up or demonstrate something I'm working on, I direct people to the site, and they just navigate the apache-provided directory structure.

What I'd like to do, I think, is have a setup where I can control which of the subdirectories in `/srv/www` are available to people, by mapping them to a URL path with its own basic auth. So for instance, `/srv/www/blog` would be available at `mydomain.com/blog`

Do I need a seperate config for each folder I want to serve up, and more importantly, what does the directive look like to map `mydomain.com/blog` to the `/srv/www/blog`, and say, `mydomain.com/wiki` to `/srv/www/wiki`?

Comment: Read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html . Then, if you have a specific question about something that doesn't work, you're welcome ot ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development/demos, I find it better to set up separate sites in Apache with a wildcard DNS entry like *.mydevcompany.com resolving to my staging Web server's public IP.

This accomplishes several things:

- Some web apps don't like to be in a sub-directory
- Improves security isolation between apps (i.e. a directory traversal vulnerability in one app could compromise another)
- easier to setup backups and keep client data separate
- easier to configure SSL and non-SSL sites without conflicting

With the wildcard DNS, you just have to create your site configuration in Apache and the wildcard DNS does all the work:

```
ServerName someclient.mydevcompany.com
ServerAlias someclient.mydevcompany.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/someclient.mydevcompany.com
```

Note: I also like to create separate config files in `sites-available`, one for each site, to keep it organized.